# How to find Choose(m, n) mod P for large m and n?

Tags: algorithms, combinations

$P = 10^9 + 7$

$Choose(m, n) = \frac{m!}{n!(m - n)!}$

I want to calculate the value of $Choose(m, n) \mod P$ for large $m$ and $n$. How can I do that in C++ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem

Comment: How large are your $m, n$? $10^6$?

Answer (score 1):

Express $m$ and $n$ in base p so that $m = \sum_{i=0}^k m_i p^i, n = \sum_{i=0}^k n_i p^i$.

Set $a_{-1} = 1$.  Compute $a_i := {m_i \choose n_i}a_{i-1} \mod p$ for $i = 0, \dots, k$.

The result $a_k$ equals ${m \choose n} \mod p$ by [Lucas' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem#Formulation).